# Can I attach a modal to a navbar link?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have created both a basic modal and navbar in HTML and I am wanting to attach said modal to a navbar link. Is this something that can be achieved with just HTML or JS?

All of the research I've conducted points me to either php or bootstrap which is out of the scope of what I'm trying to use. I am just trying to stick with either HTML or JS.

Comment: Opening a modal via a navbar link should be no different than opening it via any other link/button. I suggest including your code in the question. Without it, there's no way anyone could tell you why what you tried is not working.

Comment: Even with not much to go on you still helped me. Thank you. What was throwing me off was the initial href , but I just added the class/id from my initial modal button to the nav link and Wallah! Thanks again!